# Rest server returns 400 if object has a non empty list inside of it

Tags: java, rest

Thank you for reading this as I need help !

I have an object something like this:

```
public class MainObject {
    //some random primitives
    List<SubObject> mySubObjects. 
}
```

Then I have a REST POST call on my client:

```
    List<MainObject> mainList = getMainList();

    // cycle that breaks everything :(
    for (MainObject mainObject : mainList) {
        mainObject.setMySubObject(getSubObject());
    }

    HttpEntity<List<MainObject>> request = new HttpEntity<>(mainList);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            MyEndPoint, HttpMethod.POST, request,
            String.class);
```

So my problem is that if I remove that cycle (see code on top) everything runs smoothly, my server gathers the data and all goes fine (except that I don't have the sub objects).

BUT if I run with that cycle that populates part of my main object, well then I receive a 400 Bad Request... And I have no idea why.

The objects transferred between server and client exists on both sides and are identical I made sure of that.

Any idea ? Please...

Comment: We can't possibly know why some unknow server returns a 400 error. Look at the body of the response. Look at the logs, and/or the code of the server. Look at the documentation of the REST service, to know what is acceptable as input for this service.

Answer (score 0):

I found it ! There was a default constructor missing on the server side !